# How to change the text dynamically from a customButton on FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, button, text, dynamic, fullcalendar

I cannot figure out how to change the text of a customButton after it has been initialized. From the sample code below, the text is set to "custom!". But I want to change it dynamically? Is there a jQuery method call that I can achieve this?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    customButtons: {
        myCustomButton: {
            text: 'custom!',
            click: function() {
                alert('clicked the custom button!');
            }
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
});
```

Comment: you can set options dynamically like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/ - you might have to redefine the whole customButtons property at once though. Give it a try.

Comment: When exactly do you want to change the text, I mean what event would trigger it?  When you click it?  When events load?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I want to change the text when I click on the custom button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there already.  [The docs say](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/) that when defining custom buttons, the `click` parameter is:

> a callback function that is called when the button is clicked. Accepts a single argument, a jqueryEvent.

So just use it, for example:

```
customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
        text: 'custom!',
        click: function() {
            $(this).text('Updated text!');
        }
    }
},
```

You'll probably want to pass in some dynamic data, maybe about the currently displayed month or week or whatever.  For example (this is just an example, maybe you don't need anything like this):

```
customButtons: {
    myCustomButton: {
        text: 'custom!',
        click: function() {
            var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
            $(this).text('First visible day is ' + view.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: @dont-panic : This is what I was looking for! It does exactly what I asked for. Thanks.

Comment: this answer has a problem when we navigate the date with prev and next button

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JS :

```
customButtons: {
  showMore: {
    text: moreHoursTranslation,
    click: function (e) {
      if (this.classList.contains("more-hours")) {
        this.classList.remove("more-hours");
        this.innerText = moreHoursTranslation;
        this.closest(".fc").querySelector(".fc-view").style.height =
          "200px";
        this.closest(".fc").querySelector(".fc-view").style.overflow =
          "auto";
        return;
      }
      this.classList.add("more-hours");
      this.innerText = lessHoursTranslation;
      this.closest(".fc").querySelector(".fc-view").style.height = "auto";
      this.closest(".fc").querySelector(".fc-view").style.overflow = "auto";
    },
  },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code to add button with event binding.

```
$('.fc-toolbar .fc-left').prepend(
            $('<button type="button" class="fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">+ room</button>')
                .on('click', function() {
                    var title = prompt('Room name');
                    if (title) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
                            'addResource',
                            { title: title },
                            true // scroll to the new resource?
                        );
                    }
                })
        );
```

Reference From Bellow Link.
[Link](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.0.0-beta/demos/dynamic-add-remove.html)

Comment: this appears to be entirely unrelated to the question, which is about the use of customButtons, and how to change the title etc of the button after it has been initialised. Your example appears to be about binding to existing buttons and adding a resource when the button is clicked. Perhaps you can explain more clearly how this answers the question, because I can't see how it would help.

Comment: @ADyson if you have noticed that we are appending as button html so in that we can give label what we needed. In above code i have given another option for same (Custom button) use.

Comment: yes but I'll repeat - a) the question is about the customButtons feature specifically, and b) it asks how to change the title of the button after it's clicked, not how to add a resource. That part of your code in particular is entirely irrelevant. Looks like you just cut and paste something from another page, without even modifying it to suit the scenario.